# NFC matching between iOS and Android

Tags: flutter

I am working on an app that will need to sent data from iOS to Android using NFC. That data will be simply a string.
Is this doable with Flutter ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be use this lib : [NFC reader](https://github.com/matteocrippa/flutter-nfc-reader)